# Class Cast Exception : cannot be cast to class

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am following a below tutorial on how to send email using spring boot

https://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-boot-tutorials/how-to-send-email-using-spring-boot

I implemented it in spring boot and it is working fine. Now I am trying to implement this in my visual studio code project. I did as mentioned in the tutorial. But I am getting this error when I run my project which I cannot understand and am unable to resolve.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class 
MailServiceImpl cannot be cast to 
class MailService (MailServiceImpl and MailService are in unnamed module of 
loader 'app') at
Application.main(Application.java:28)
```

To see my MailService and MailServiceImpl Classes, please visit the mentioned link.Kindly help!

Comment: How do you run the app?

Comment: I have a launch.json file already there for my project. By going to run option and then clicking the launch button. I am able to run the project sucessfully If I remove this email code. I don't think the error is related to this. @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Can you show whats on line 28 of Application

Comment: so you do have in mailServiceImpl the information that It implements MailService?

Comment: Please post MailServiceImpl

Comment: Show your MailServiceImpl, please.

Comment: @Sudoss No this does not have any response. I have marked the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have missed something when declare MailServiceImpl
Correctly, it should be

```
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {
}
```

Comment: yes you are right. I missed this part. Thank you!